# [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002010] Cannot subscribe to topic: bethlehem with token: (null)

Tags: ios, firebase-notifications

I am working with Swift 3, iOS 10 project.

I am currently working with Firebase notification, I can receive notification through Postman at Firebase Console (Notifications) for generic notification.

I would like to subscribe app users to a "topic".

As I've searched, I need 2 section to subscribe app users,

[image: application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]

[image: fcm token refresh]

That's my code, one for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and fcm token refresh. But I am still getting the error.

Also, I tried using "/topics/bethlehem"

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: I am getting the same error, anyone please suggest!